# Getting campaign monthly data vai linkedin marketing api

Tags: linkedin-api

Question is how can I get campaign data for only monthly base.I need to find out the campaign spend over last 30 days or 1 month.
I need to get only last 30 days campaign data,

I'm using this api to get data

```
url: `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adCampaigns?q=search&search=(account:(values:List(urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A${customer_id})))`,
    headers: {
      'LinkedIn-Version': '202302',
      'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
      'X-RestLi-Method': 'finder',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
```